# Is it possible to multiply blockwise

Tags: matrices

$M=[0_{n\times n_1},0_{n\times n_2},I_{n_3}]\times[P_1,R_1,Q_1]^{-1}$ where $P_1,R_1,Q_1$ is of size $n\times n_1,n\times n_2,n\times n_3$ and $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$
my question is is it possible to simplyfy the product?

Comment: You can multiply blockwise and you can take blockwise inverses if the diagonal blocks are square, but I don't think you can take blockwise inverses if all the blocks are rectangular.

Comment: I was also thinking the same thank you